# Proving $[\triangle{ABC}]=[\triangle{ADC}]$

Tags: geometry

The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ of a quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at $O$.

If $BO=OD$, prove that $[\triangle{ABC}]=[\triangle{ADC}]$

I proved $[\triangle{AOB}]=[\triangle{AOD}]$
But, I can not continue further.

[image]

Comment: Triangles of same base $AC$ and equal heights.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you! So easy!

Comment: How do we know the diagonals are perpendicular to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles have the same base and altitude ( marked red), so their half product = area, is same.

[image]